# Does an Indian national with a USA green card need a transit visa for the Frankfurt airport

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, transit-visas, fra

I am traveling from the US to India and have a stop at the Frankfurt airport. I was wondering if I would need a transit visa while I am at the airport.

Comment: Just to save you from having to sort through the other question and its answers: if you need to clear passport control in Frankfurt then you need a regular Schengen short-stay visa, type C.  If you do not need to clear passport control then your green card exempts you from the transit visa requirement.  Keep in mind that if your flight that leaves Frankfurt is going to another Schengen airport (in other words, if you have two stops in the Schengen area) then you will need to clear passport control so you'll need a type C visa.